# Manage Other User Accounts via Firebase auth()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to the [Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) section in the Firebase docs, user profiles can be modified using the methods below

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

All of the  examples in this guide seem tailored to only the `currentUser` that is signed in, but how can we modify other users programatically? Is there a `getUser(uid)` method  that I'm not seeing?

It seems this can be done with the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK, but how can we do this from the Web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web implementation of the Authentication API is intended to be used client-side only. To edit another user, you would have to authenticate/login as that user. Which would mean `currentUser` would be the user you require.

You should do this server-side using the Admin API. Which is a separate API.

Setup: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/

Manage Users: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users